# When New Row Enter Remove Oldest

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a message system, and I wan't to make happend this:

When user send message, his message is stored in the database when "Sent Box" reaches limit of 15 when new messages are stored it should delete the oldest record to give space to the new!

I've tried a lot of solutions in the web but none worked :(

Comment: here is a keyword for you: `sql trigger`

Comment: I'm not understanding :(

Comment: Just google for "sql" and "trigger" and you will learn that database triggers wait for events (such as an insert in a table) and then do something (such as delete a record from a table). This is what you are looking for.

Comment: Or just store all of them, only display the last 15 to the user, and run a periodic cron job to delete old ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this may help

create a query to count no. of rows in the table

*select count(*) from table.........

then while inserting a new message you check whether count is =15 or not.
if it is then first execute the delete query as below-

delete from table_name where sentat=(select min(sentat) from table_name)

after that execute insert query.

Comment: What if there is more than one user?

Comment: WHERE id='' AND id=''

Comment: Or just create an array an use implode function like:

"(...) WHERE id IN (".implode(",",$ARRAY.")"

@Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

I used this "ORDER BY `sentat` DESC LIMIT 1"